# Capistrano "no such file or directory - git ls-remote git@github.com"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, git, ruby-on-rails-3.1, capistrano, bundler

I built a rails app and i am currently in the process of deploying it from my windows system to vexxhost (a hosting company). I have a repository on github and i have followed all the procedures of deploying my rails app. Everything was going fine until i typed "cap deploy:cold",after which the following error was Displayed.

[image]

My deploy.rb file

```
 require 'bundler/capistrano'
 require 'capistrano'
 require 'capistrano-vexxhost'


  # Account Settings

  ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true

  set :user, "innocent"
  set :password, "2Q0bNx85it"
  set :domain, "legoads.com"
  set :mount_path,"/home/innocent/public_html"
  set :application,"legoads"
  set :scm, :git
  set :repository, "git@github.com:innoc/Legoads.git"
  default_run_options[:pty] = true
```

Comment: Do you have git installed in the server?

Answer (score 1):

From the error it appears that git isn't installed in the remote server. Install git and try again, or better, make a capistrano recipe to setup your server, which will among other tasks install git.